# Unable to parse Json to Object : JPA ManytoOne unidirectional

Tags: spring, jpa, jackson, json-deserialization

I am using spring data rest with repositories, db is mysql.

I have objects Parent and child. Relationship is Many  to one .

child to Parent relationship is unidirectional. I do not have List of child obj inside Parent.

```
Parent{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   protected Long id = null;

   @NotNull(message = "name of user should not be null")
   @Size(min=2, max=30)
   private String name;

}

Child{ 

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I have an parent "1" and i want to refer it to newly creating child. The json input for new child "POST" req is

```
 {
   "name":"child name",
    "parent":{
        "id":1
     }  
  }
```

Need help in associating parent "1" in newly creating child.

Is there any changes required in json format? I tried with "parent_id" as well but still having error.

Comment: Could be validation error. user requires `name'

Comment: User is already created. I just want to refer the user in application.

Comment: @Dark it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since spring-data-rest uses HATEOAS. The following format worked.

```
{
 "name":"testname1",
 "parent": "http://localhost:8080/parent/2"
}
```

Thanks to all who tried to answer.